# Year as an index

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I had this dictionary

```
"name" : {
        "2016" : {
            "1" : "info"
        }
}
```

I added it to sessionStorage using json.stringfy and it worked perfectly. I then appended another dictionary to the first one:

```
name: {
    2016: {
        1: {
            info: {
                0: {
                    "question": "qs1",
                    "information": "info1"
                },
                1: {
                    "question": "qs12",
                    "information": "info2"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I did the same convert to a string using json.stringfy. Then I noticed this:

```
name: {
    0 : "2016",
    1 : null,
    2 : null, //until 2016
    2016: {
        1: {
            info: {
                0: {
                    "question": "qs1",
                    "information": "info1"
                },
                1: {
                    "question": "qs12",
                    "information": "info2"
                },
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know why it's counting when the typeof tells me that it's a string, not a number. Also, I don't understand why it didn't do this with the first dictionary.

Here is the code:

```
(function($){
x = {
    "info": {
        "0": {
            "question": "qs1",
            "information": "info1"
        },
        "1": {
            "question": "qs12",
            "information": "info2"
        },
    }
}

var sesion = {};
var stringinfo;
sesion["name"]=["2016"];
sesion["name"]["2016"]=["1"];
sesion["name"]["2016"]["1"] = x;

stringinfo = json.stringfy(sesion);

console.log(sesion);
console.log(stringinfo)
}(jQuery))
```

Try it and tell me if using a number(string) as an index does that! How can I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: i see an object with `name ...`, maybe you consider to use an array instead of an object for `info`.

Comment: When setting an actual array's index like `array[2016]` if the previous 2015 elements were not set you are going to have undefined indexes, hence why you get null when you stringify/parse

Comment: How are you appending the two dictionaries?

Comment: in this way
let sesion = {};
sesion['name'] = ['2016'];
sesion['name']['2016'] = [1];
sesion['name']['2016'] [1] = infoArray;
sessionStorage.setItem('value', JSON.stringify(sesion));

Comment: **infoArray** i got from an ajax

Comment: see here https://jsfiddle.net/jtejeda/qu0v8r01/5/

Comment: `sesion["name"]=["2016"];
sesion["name"]["2016"]=["1"];
sesion["name"]["2016"]["1"] = x;`  <--- that is arrays not objects, not what you say you have

Answer (score 2):

you are confusing arrays (`[]`) and objects (`{}`). At the beginning you say:

> I got this array:
>
> ```
> "name" : {
>         "2016" : {
>             "1" : "info"
>         }
> ```

But this is an object.

Your question is a bit difficult to follow. But if you instantiate an empty array, and tell it that numer 2016 should have a certain value, it will fill up the rest with empty (`null`) values.

You want to use an object, rather than an array. 
Look at your code where objects and arrays get mixed up. You want to be using an object, with the key "2016", not an array which uses numbers as indexes.

**added information after reviewing supplied code**

(btw I fixed spelling of 'sesion' to 'session' in explanation below)

the line:

```
var session = {}
```

makes an empty object. The line:

```
session["name"]=["2016"];
```

sets the property `"name"` of this object to be an array containing the only string `"2016"`.
Now it gets interesting; you just made the `name` property an array, so the line

```
session["name"]["2016"]=["1"];
```

makes the compiler use the following logic; since session["name"] is an array, you probably don't mean to set a property on it when you refer to `session["name"]["2016"]`; the string "2016" gets coerced to a number and it puts a new array on it, containing the string "1".

At this point I must point out that your code is not running, and after fixing it the output is not like you put it in your question. What happens after is the same as before, just you put in the new array at the 1st spot your object in `x`.

The main problem in your code as stated before sits in mixing arrays and objects.

replace the line

```
session["name"]=["2016"];
```

for example with:

```
session["name"] = {}
```

to instantiate an object on which you can put properties such as "2016", and I am not sure what the exact objective is, but if you want to make an array under this property, do it something like:

```
session["name"]["2016"]=[x];
```

Comment: maybe I expressed wrong, see here! https://jsfiddle.net/jtejeda/qu0v8r01/5/